# How to declare strings globally in react native

Tags: android, string, react-native

I have a lot of strings in my `react-native` application. I see some of strings are being used at multiple places. IMO I do not want to hard code strings in my code as this is not good approach. It may takes ages to change same strings on multiple locations if project go on large scale.

What approaches is to declare strings of react native application. I do android development where it has `strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="string_name"
        >text_string</string>
</resources>
```

What I am doing in JS files.

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center" }}>
  Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you.
</Text>
```

Comment: You can just have a constants object that you import everywhere you need these strings

Comment: @MotiAzu Can you explain with a snippet of code pls ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no specialized resource manager for strings in `React Native` like you have in `Android`.
You can have a file with all these constants exported and import them wherever you need.
Something along these lines:

```
**** constants.js

export const NeverForget = 'Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you.';
export const OtherString = 'Welcome to the app';

**** Usage:

import { NeverForget } from 'app/constants';

...
<Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center" }}>
  { NeverForget }
</Text>

**** Or

import * as constants from 'app/constants';

...
<Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center" }}>
  { constants.NeverForget }
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

Personally i would use this library to set up manager for your global strings, as it has the added benefit of controlling translations at a later date if your app scales. Also simple to set up.

Comment: I see no benefit in this library if the strings aren't going to be translated though.

Comment: The library was deprecated in favour of https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n