# How to display different app names based on device language?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm building a react-native app. Is there a way to set the app name to "English App Name" when my device language is English and display "francais" when my device language is French?

Comment: There is an answer for android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603248/how-to-declare-strings-globally-in-react-native/43604920
for iOS use the InfoPlist.Strings

Comment: This this related to my question?

Comment: You used the iOS tag.

Comment: @Bo Zhao Yes, it's related to your question. I can tell for sure, that you can use XCode to add the InfoPlist.strings to localize your react native project (add file, then use the "localize" feature). I'm not familiar with th Android ecosystem, that's why I've linked a similar question from SO. Maybe this 'guide' will be better for you: https://hackernoon.com/localize-an-application-name-in-react-native-c36c4b2be7c3
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you have to define multiple `strings.xml` file for every language like

```
strings-eg.xml

strings-fr.xml
```

and inside every file you have to declare a string for App name

```
<string name="app_name">XYZ</string>
```